# Проблема с "поехавшим" div'ом

Tags: css

Увы, не знаю как сформулировать нормальный вопрос, попробую объяснить на примерах. Мне нужно получить вот такую структуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. два блока с текстом "съезжают" по непонятной для меня причине.

```css
.source {
    background-color: #f7f7f9;
}

.source:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.source .image,
.source .data {
    display: inline-block;
}

.source .data .first-line,
.source .data .second-line {
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="source" ng-repeat="source in $ctrl.sources">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c630017/v630017880/1271e/rZi7F9_vu-8.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="first-line">
            Text 1
        </div>
        <div class="second-line">
            Text 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

П.С. В примере, почему-то, текст съезжает вниз, а не вверх, ка на картинке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавь `.source .image, .source .data { vertical-align: middle; }`

**По-умолчанию** у `inline-block` элементов выравнивание по `baseline`.

Получится:

```css
.source {
    background-color: #f7f7f9;
}

.source:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.source .image,
.source .data {
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.source .data .first-line,
.source .data .second-line {
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="source" ng-repeat="source in $ctrl.sources">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c630017/v630017880/1271e/rZi7F9_vu-8.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="first-line">
            Text 1
        </div>
        <div class="second-line">
            Text 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй в css стили для .source .image float:left А display:inline-block убери

```css
.source {
    background-color: #f7f7f9;
}

.source:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.source .image {
    float:left;
}
.source .data {
    display: inline-block;
}

.source .data .first-line,
.source .data .second-line {
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="source" ng-repeat="source in $ctrl.sources">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c630017/v630017880/1271e/rZi7F9_vu-8.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="first-line">
            Text 1
        </div>
        <div class="second-line">
            Text 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно делать на display:flex; Крайне удобный инструмент!

```
<div class="source" ng-repeat="source in $ctrl.sources">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c630017/v630017880/1271e/rZi7F9_vu-8.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="first-line">
            Text 1
        </div>
        <div class="second-line">
            Text 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.source {
  display: flex;
    background-color: #f7f7f9;
}

.source .data .first-line,
.source .data .second-line {
    height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

То что вам нужно, можно легко сделать через *flexbox*

```css
.source {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img,
.line {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.line {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="source">
  <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c630017/v630017880/1271e/rZi7F9_vu-8.jpg" />
  <div class="data">
    <div class="line">
      Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      Text 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: С каких пор ставят минусы за альтернативное *рабочее* решение?